# Lock writing Mifare Ultralight C

Tags: java, nfc, apdu

I want to lock writing the memory area of a Ultralight C. We can see in the documentation that if I set to 0xFF the page 0x2B the write access is restricted and if I set 0x00 will be both, write and read access.

Indeed, I set that the 0x2B page with 0xFF and later the page 0x2A with 0x04 to lock the memory access. It goes fine, but when I try to read any page from 0x04 it responses 63 00

Have someone done what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is set on page 0x2B the byte 0x01 and it works!